# Do I have to worry about inserts/updates/deletes/injection attacks when I use the following SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

Do I need to do anything in order to prevent inserts/updates/deletes/injection attacks when I'm using the following code?

```
public static DataSet getReportDataSet(string sqlSelectStatement)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelectStatement, new SqlConnection(GlobalVars.ConnectionString));
    DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(reportData, "reportData");
    return reportData;
}
```

The idea behind this is that I'll be extracting the sql from a series of Crystal Reports, pulling the data for each report from the MS SQL Server, binding the data to the reports and then exporting the filled reports to PDF.

I know that you can use the built in functionality to get the reports to pull their own data, but my tests have shown that pushing the data to the reports is a whole bunch faster. My only issue with this is that I have no control over the reports that will be ran.

People will be required to provide their own login credentials for the SQL Server, so they will only be able to see data from the databases that they have permissions to... but some of the users have write permissions, and I'm worried that blindly running an sql string pulled from a Crystal Report could potentially allow for an insert/update/delete/injection attack...

I think that I might be worrying for nothing, but I can't find anything that outright states if this could be used for things aside from selects.

**Edit:**

So from the initial comments, I think that I do have to worry about SQL statements aside from SELECTs. So my question now becomes; is there some whay to specify that an SqlConnection can only be used for 'reads' (i.e. Selects).

Comment: I'm not aware of any option to specify a read only connection. I only found an option for the connectionstring "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly", but this seems to be a hint only.
What about using a special user account for the reporting which has only read access?

Comment: you should never worry buddy!

Comment: @H-Man2 I was thinking about making a special read-only user account, but I'm having a difficult time working out how to apply a specific user's permissions with regards to which databases they can access, along side this read only user account. I think I'll be able to manage it, though... Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would say: Yes, you have to.

But maybe Crystal Reports quotes the SQL-String already. Try an "attack" by yourself and see what `sqlSelectStatement` contains.

Comment: Well, that's just terrifying. I made a quick Crystal Report with an SQL Command Table that had definition of: DELETE FROM tbl_Test; SELECT * FROM tbl_Test; Yep, Crystal Reports are capable of running any SQL that the user has permissions to run, so long as it ends with a select. This is really, really terrifying.

Comment: I'm going to give this one to you, as you pointed me in the dirction of finding the answer... now I just need some way to handle the potential threat.

Comment: @Chronicide: Ups. I think the developers never thought about this usage scenario. It has been a long time since I used CR. Maybe you could ask the experts here for save performance improvements.

Comment: My advice is to use only reports from trusted sources.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the adapter. The problem is, how you pass parameters to your sql command. You should **not** do things like

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE name='" + name +"'";
```

Instead use parameters:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT * FROM t WHERE name = @name", conn);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@name";
param.Value = "John Doe";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: So if the sql string happens to be "delete from tbl_Users", it won't delete my entire tbl_Users table? (My string won't have parameters... I'm pulling the complete string from a Crystal Report. I"m more worries about the potential nature of the sql)

Comment: A note to injection. It works like this: A user would enter a name like `"x'; DELETE FROM t;"`. Thus transforming your sql into `"SELECT * FROM t WHERE name='x'; DELETE FROM t;"'. The single quote in the name terminates the SELECT statement and allows to insert a nasty command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense.... and I've done some more reading on how using SqlParameters prevents this sort of issue. What I'm apprehensive about is the entire sql string, which will come from an external source and has no parameters. I see the dataadapter has selectcommand, insertcommand, updatecommand, etc... If I assigne the SqlCommand to the selectcommand property directly, does this ensure that only select statements will be executed?

Comment: As H-Man2 suggests, try to create a Crystal Reports report based on a query like:  `"SELECT * FROM t; DELETE FROM t WHERE name='test';" and see if it works!